# Can "low quality post" review task be made more clear?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, answers

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181165/can-flags-send-a-post-into-the-low-quality-posts-review-queue/190639), a question can make it into a "low quality" review queue because it was flagged as "not an answer."  But the review task does not make any mention of it.  It simply says that a post was flagged as low quality because of its length or content.  There is a subtle difference, but it is there.

It's possible that an interesting non-answer is marked as "not an answer", but then it won't get deleted because reviewers will see "poor quality because of length or content" heading when presented with review tasks for that answer.  And they won't agree with the assessment because they find the answer either interesting or appealing.  The fact that it may be a poor answer to the question, as it was asked, simply may not enter a reviewer's field of attention.

The description in the review task should better reflect the flag (or at least the possibility that the answer made it into low-quality queue because of this flag).  Can it be changed to say "this answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content or because it does not make an attempt to answer the question?"

Comment: You should be able to just scroll down and see the question itself.  In faded text, unfortunately for readability, but it's there as I recall.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, the task is to put the post in one of three bins: looks ok, edit or remove. I don't think people really look at what it was flagged for because that doesn't really matter. Those reviewing have been around long enough to know how the Q&A system works and they should know enough about the rules to complete the task of judging if a post is fine or not (which is essentially what it boils down to).

For more information about the review queues, see [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/387405).

A little bit about the three bins:

#### Looks ok

Use this if you think the post is fine as it is. You effectively vote to keep it as it is.

#### Edit

Use this if you think the post is alright except for a few minor thing which you change by editing. This option implicitly contains the *looks ok* vote (see the aforementioned meta answer).

#### Delete or Recommend Deletion (if you lack the [Trusted User Privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user))

This is the third option. Use this if you want the post removed. This option might seem to have many sub-options, but those (except for the first) you see when clicking on the button are meant to leave a predefined comment under the post so the user is notified.

You can always choose to leave no comment and still vote to delete. Alternatively, you can also leave your own comment. Leaving a comment can also help future reviewers if it's not entirely clear what the problem is.

Comment: It doesn't matter what people "should" do.  Even those who are competent only display competence *most* of the time.  Those who are *somewhat competent* display competence on occasion.  Having a more clear description would only serve to remind people of what's going on.  That's the argument *for* more clarity.  What's the argument against clarity?

Comment: @grovkin if you feel that strongly about this, I think you should consider asking it on SE Meta rather than this beta site's meta. As far as I know, the message is the same on all sites (and I don't really see why it would be a problem here and now).